# Remove extra x axis values

Tags: c#, charts, dotnetcharting

I'm having trouble removing extra values in the x column. Basically, my graph doesn't start at 0, nor does it end at my last data point. I have tried starting the axis at 0, as well as setting the interval offset to -20 (my interval is 20).

Is there any way i can get rid of the extra values on either side of my data?

```
string[] xValues = new string[5] { "QE1", "QE2", "QE3", "QE4", $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}" };

        PlotBaselines(xValues);

        var amCost = new Series()
        {
            Name = "AmCost",
            Color = Color.Blue,
            IsVisibleInLegend = true,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };
        impairmentGraph.Series.Add(amCost);
        // Test Values 0 - 20
        float[] amCostValues = new float[5] { 5, 15, 20, 13, 6 };
        impairmentGraph.Series["AmCost"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, amCostValues);
```

Here is the code for a series. Each is the same.

`impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
            impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 20;
            impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = -20;
            impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;`

Here is the only set up code I'm using.

[image: Picture illustrating my issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` of your x-axis.

But: This can **only** work if you have added the x-values as **numbers** ( or datetimes) **!** Yours are not!

Here are changes that will help:

Change the xvalues to numbers:

```
 double[] xValues = new double[5] {  1,2,3,4,5 };
```

Put your labels in another array:

```
 string[] xLabels = new string[5] { "QE1", "QE2", "QE3", "QE4", 
                                    $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}" };
```

After binding the data you need to set the `AxisLabels` for the `DataPoints`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; i++)
            impairmentGraph.Series["AmCost"].Points[i].AxisLabel = xLabels[i];
```

Now you can set the range the x-axis shall display:

```
 impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
 impairmentGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;
```

With my data the result looks like this:

[image]

Note that when you add x-values as `string` they will all be **converted** to `double` resulting in a values of **0.0d**  **for all points**. (Do check this in the debugger!!) Therefore you can't use them anymore for **anything** at all; not for setting the range nor for formatting the labels or for feeding `Tooltips` etc..

The fact that the strings are first fed into the `AxisLabels` misleads many folks to assume that all is well, it isn't..

Also note that I always chose List over arrays and that this rather fixed set of data doesn't reall profit from databinding, especially since we need to access each `DataPoint` anyway..

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I will try this at work on Monday.