# How do I get rid of empty data points in my chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a chart that I am using in my C# .NET Windows Forms Application. It looks like this:
[image]

If you notice along the X-axis, at points (0,0) and (9, 0) that there is no data being fed into my chart's dataset. This is not a coincidence: I only feed data to this chart that will have "Production Hour" from 1-8.

How can I get rid of the 0 and 9 along the x-axis? I don't want a "blank column" of data added to each "side" (beginning/end) of my chart. It seems it is the default behavior of a `Chart` in .NET Windows Forms Applications to add an extra point along the x-axis on both ends of the dataset (start/end). Perhaps there is an easy way to toggle that feature off?

In other words, I would like the "start point" of my chart to be 1 (on the x axis) and I would like the "end point" of chart to be 8 (also on the x axis).

This is a normal chart you would drag/drop onto the UI if you are using Windows Forms Application.

Comment: The chart looks fine. The chart's start and end must appear *somewhere* and it can't be inside the bars. Beyond that, we can't guess what the code does, what the data looks like or what chart component is used. You may be able to modify the start and end of the X axis, or not. You may be able to show the bars on the left of the ticks so you can start from `1` but you still need to decide where to show the bars for `8`. Perhaps the chart you use handles this, perhaps not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048193/blank-spaces-added-to-either-side-of-x-axis-values-microsoft-charting --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769980/14171304 --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602599/14171304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my question using the answer from user [digEmAll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316644/digemall) for this post:
[Remove blanks at ends of DataVisualization chart x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060239/remove-blanks-at-ends-of-datavisualization-chart-x-axis)

This is the code itself that fixed my problem:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;   // if your minimum X = 1
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 8; // if your maximum X = 8
```

I'm unsure if there is a way to set this in properties of a chart (I'd rather set this there). But for now, I placed this code on a button click event (the button queries data and loads it into my chart). Thus, whenever data is present in my chart, the min and max will be set to the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem.
In my case it was enough to change
`MyChart.Series("New").Points.AddXY(WeekNumber, SomeValue)`
to 
`MyChart.Series("New").Points.AddXY(WeekNumber.ToSting, SomeValue)`
Looks like when there are numbers in X axis those are automatically added at the start and end of the axis.